# Show accuracy and loss with model.predict()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to know if it's possible to know the loss/accuracy with *model.predict()* in Keras?

I tried to figured out by myself, but I failed. Thank you very much for any inputs.

Comment: Please show your attempt as how the guideline specified. We can only guide you after you shown what you have tried. And yes it is possible.

Comment: @seraph how is it possible? what method do you use? Is it by using ```model.evaluate()```?

Answer (score 3):

[Keras `model.predict()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) only gets the input data (`X`) and produces the output from the trained model. It does not know anything about the actual expected value (`y`).
You can do what you are asking for using [model.evaluate()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate), that actually requires the `X` and `y` values in your data set and will produce the loss value and metrics values for the model in test mode.

Use `model.predict()` in production, to just get the model output. During your testing and validation phase, you may want to also use `model.evaluate()`.

Comment: To help I need to know how you provided your data to model.fit. Are the labels encoded as categorical? Did you provide the data using generators? Did you use flow, flow_from_directory or flow_from_dataframe?

Comment: In my project I used ImageDataGenerator, with the labels coded as one-hot encoded vectors. I used flow_from_dataframe.

Comment: see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67147027/display-an-image-and-its-label-from-dataframeiterator/67151538#67151538

Answer (score 1):

So my code is like this :

```
    # Fetch dataset
train_data, test_data = tfds.load(name="imdb_reviews", split=["train", "test"], 
                              batch_size=-1, as_supervised=True)

train_examples, train_labels = tfds.as_numpy(train_data)
test_examples, test_labels = tfds.as_numpy(test_data)

np.save("train_examples", train_examples)
np.save("train_labels", train_labels)

np.save("test_examples", test_examples)
np.save("test_labels", test_labels)
# BUILD MODEL
model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[], input_shape=[], 
                       dtype=tf.string, trainable=True, name='gnews_embedding')

model = build_model(hub_layer)
model.summary()
# SAVE AS CHECKPOINT (THE BEST ONLY)
es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, verbose=1, mode='min')
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)

# TRAIN MODEL
history = model.fit(
                train_examples,
                train_labels,
                epochs=20,
                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                validation_split = .2,
                shuffle = True,
                callbacks = [checkpoint, es],
                verbose=1)

# CHECK ACCURACY AND LOSS VALUE
model.load_weights('/app/model.h5')
results = model.evaluate(test_examples, test_labels)

text = "The gold rush apple from natora- this is the most expensive apple."
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([text])
np.save("test_txt", test_txt)
resultsTest = model.evaluate(dataset, test_labels)
print("RESULT ACCURACY = ", resultsTest)
```

so I try to know the accuracy/loss of this prediction. Can i evaluate a simple sentence like that or just re-train the model to get the loss/accuracy ?